# Node.js Stream on Typescript: supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: typescript, node.js-stream

In typescript I was trying to implement custom transform stream. But it was giving me typescript error `supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target` when I call `super` contructor with `options`.

```
var Transform = require('stream').Transform
export class Test extends Transform {
  constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because TypeScript does not know the type of the constructor of `Transform` when you are resolving it using `require`. You can use the `import` syntax to import `Transform`:

```
import { Transform, TransformOptions } from "stream";

export class Test extends Transform {
    constructor(options: TransformOptions) {
        super(options);
    }
}
```

Make sure you have the typings for node installed:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```